# Saving Image from UIImageView after manipulating Gestures

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, save, gesture

I'm trying to save the image after manipulating it with move, pinch and rotate gestoures.

All I get is the real image no matter what I tried,

I tried with UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions on the UIView container and on the UIIMageView without success.

Hope someone can help on this one.

Thanks,

Itay

Comment: could you just show the code you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0.0);

CGContextConcatCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), imageView.transform);
[imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This is assuming your `imageView` is transformed by means of a `CGAffineTransform` applied to it.