# iOS Drawing image with objects (arrows) and saving to disk

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, uiimage, core-image

I am creating a iOS drawing application that allows the user to place arrows on the page and position/stretch/rotate them. When the user saves the image, I must modify the background image with the png arrows at the exact coordinate they were dragged to.

[image]

The 3 drag-able parts will be UIImage's with CapInsets to keep the arrow looking normal when stretched. The canvas UIImageView will have the same aspect as the actual image ensuring no black space is visible.

My questions is this. After a drag-able part has been stretched, how do I save the results of the UIImageView (the smaller drag-able parts) to disk/memory for later modifying of the background image (the background UIImageView canvas). It is important to ensure what image I used to modify the canvas looks exactly the same as the UIImageView drag-able part that represented it. That means that it must retain exactly how the image is displayed, including the CapInsets.

I am ignoring rotation of the drag-able parts for now because I suspect that would be the easy part.

Comment: I fail tu understand what is it you want to save. Is it the "screenshot" image or data to recreate the scene for modification?

Comment: Just edited to clarify more. I need to save the smaller UIImageViews after they have been moved/stretched/rotated. That way, I can later "recreate" the seen directly on the UIImage housed in the background UIImageView canvas

Comment: Have you tried getting image from layer? That way you can get image from any view in current state.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I found this that might do the trick. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14758060/saving-image-from-uiimageview-after-manipulating-gestures

Comment: If you make your comment an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code to get a layer screenshot from a desired view:

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromLayer:(CALayer *)layer {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([layer frame].size);
    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outputImage;
}
```